# SSO integration in Azure B2C and SABA using SAML (IdP) request

Tags: azure, single-sign-on, azure-ad-b2c, saml, saba

We tried with 2 different approaches, where we are facing different issues.
**Approach 1:** [Tutorial: Azure Active Directory single sign-on (SSO) integration with Saba Cloud | Microsoft Docs](https://nam04.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Factive-directory%2Fsaas-apps%2Fsaba-cloud-tutorial&data=04%7C01%7Csachin.mahajan%40newhorizons.com%7Ca30628dc9a14425ac15508d963d69d7e%7Cae46f825dc0d4f549a2cbcddc943d655%7C0%7C0%7C637650596180997428%7CUnknown%7CTWFpbGZsb3d8eyJWIjoiMC4wLjAwMDAiLCJQIjoiV2luMzIiLCJBTiI6Ik1haWwiLCJXVCI6Mn0%3D%7C1000&sdata=cv01G6pr7uDHZDIU1zH5xAIJCLNaRnQjkijDdfUsnbg%3D&reserved=0): Issue is mentioned in below steps.
**Approach 2:** [Configure Azure Active Directory B2C as a SAML IdP to your applications | Microsoft Docs](https://nam04.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Factive-directory-b2c%2Fsaml-service-provider%3Ftabs%3Dwindows%26pivots%3Db2c-custom-policy&data=04%7C01%7Csachin.mahajan%40newhorizons.com%7Ca30628dc9a14425ac15508d963d69d7e%7Cae46f825dc0d4f549a2cbcddc943d655%7C0%7C0%7C637650596181002408%7CUnknown%7CTWFpbGZsb3d8eyJWIjoiMC4wLjAwMDAiLCJQIjoiV2luMzIiLCJBTiI6Ik1haWwiLCJXVCI6Mn0%3D%7C1000&sdata=tL%2BM0ErGkERcQQkW88nw%2BjbtSorDzwDz1RFzv9c6E5I%3D&reserved=0): Issue - entity id is not populating in SABA cloud.

Below are steps of Approach 1.
Step 1: We have created one enterprise application with entity id e.g. xyz_sp. xyz_sp is provided by SABA Cloud team. 
Step 2: We shared a SAML metadata file with SABA cloud team.
Step 3: SABA Cloud team configured the SAML metadata file and it is working like https://xyz.sabacloud.com
The issue here is:
The enterprise application that we configured is uses AD login, but we want B2C login window.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use an enterprise application.

For B2C, you have to use a custom policy.

The B2C metadata is different. As per the article, generate B2C specific metadata and send it to the vendor.

What do you mean by:

"entity id is not populating in SABA cloud"?

Are you using IDP or SP initiated?

Comment: We are using IDP initiated. 

SABA cloud team created one entity (e,g, xyz) for SSO with B2C.  Using this entity id we follow steps in URL (approach 2 URL in my question) and created a metadata file. Using this metadata, entity id is not populating in SABA.